# Failed to execute "git archive -o export.zip develop $(git diff --name-only old new)" in bat

Tags: git, batch-file

This command can be executed in the terminal, but it cannot be successfully executed in the bat file
prompting error: unknown option `name-only'

I tried using cmd file and bat file, tried administrator run,still doesn't work

Comment: $()` is specific to bash, it doesn't work in batch files.

Comment: How to write in batch file